# Jersey REST consumer over https

Tags: rest, https, jersey, mule

I was using this Jersey annotated Rest consumer POJO without any issue over http, but then we had to start deploying our app over HTTPS.
I am getting a big fat 404, and I concluded, that everything else worked in the code (which is running over MULE beautifully btw) and my POJO simply doesn't consume HTTPS requests.
I suspect that

1. I am out of luck and Jersey doesn't speak https and I have to redo something here or revert back the part to http
2. There is a pretty little annotation that i add and voiala! all good.
   Obviously, hoping for 2. here.
   Here is the code:

   package org.acme.api;

   import java.net.UnknownHostException;
   import java.util.List;

   import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
   import javax.ws.rs.GET;
   import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
   import javax.ws.rs.Path;
   import javax.ws.rs.POST;
   import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
   import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
   import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
   import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

   import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
   import com.mongodb.BasicDBList;
   import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
   import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
   import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
   import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
   import com.mongodb.DBObject;
   import com.mongodb.WriteResult;
   import com.mongodb.util.JSON;
   import com.mongodb.DB;

   /**

   - REST Web service implementation.
   - - @author menashe@acme.org
       */

   @Path("/")

   public class Product {

   MongoClient client = null;
   DB db = null;
   DBCollection products = null;

   public Product() throws UnknownHostException {
       this.client = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27027));
       this.db = this.client.getDB("dailysale");
       this.products = this.db.getCollection("products");
   }

   @GET
   @Produces("application/json")
   @Path("/product/{productId}")
   public String retrieveProduct(@PathParam("productId") Integer productId) {

   ```
   String product;

   try{

       DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("productId", String.valueOf(productId));
       product = this.products.findOne(query).toString();

   } catch(Exception e) {

       product = "{ error: 'We were not able to find product with Id: '" + productId + ". " + e.getLocalizedMessage() + " }";
   }

   return product;
   ```

   }

   @GET
   @Produces("application/json")
   @Path("/product/grid/{query}")
   @HeaderParam("range")
   public Response listProducts(@HeaderParam("range") String range, @PathParam("query") String query) {

   ```
   Integer pageNum = 1;
   Integer pageSize = 10;

   Integer resultCount = null; 

   BasicDBList result = new BasicDBList();

   Integer firstItem = (pageNum - 1 ) * pageSize;

   Long allProductsCount = null;

   Integer lastItem = null;

   DBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject("$regex", query);

   try {
       DBCursor productListCursor = products.find(searchQuery).skip(firstItem).limit( pageSize );

       List<DBObject>  productList = productListCursor.toArray();

       for(DBObject product : productList) { 

           result.add(this.itemToGridConverter(product));

       }

       resultCount = productList.size();

       allProductsCount = products.count();

       lastItem = firstItem + resultCount - 1;

   } catch(Exception e) {

       result = new BasicDBList();
       result.add(new BasicDBObject("error", "We were not able to retrieve all products with pageSize: " + pageSize + " and pageNumber " + pageNum + ". " + e.getLocalizedMessage() ));

   }

   return Response.ok(result).header("Content-Range",  "items " + firstItem + "-" + lastItem + "/" + allProductsCount).build();
   ```

   }

   @GET
   @Produces("application/json")
   @Path("/product/grid/")
   @HeaderParam("range")
   public Response listProducts(@HeaderParam("range") String range) {

   ```
   Integer pageNum = 1;
   Integer pageSize = 10;

   Integer resultCount = null; 

   BasicDBList result = new BasicDBList();

   Integer firstItem = (pageNum - 1 ) * pageSize;

   Long allProductsCount = null;

   Integer lastItem = null;

   try {
       DBCursor productListCursor = products.find().skip(firstItem).limit( pageSize ).sort( new BasicDBObject( "sku", 1)) ;

       List<DBObject>  productList = productListCursor.toArray();

       for(DBObject product : productList) { 

           result.add(this.itemToGridConverter(product));

       }

       resultCount = productList.size();

       allProductsCount = products.count();

       lastItem = firstItem + resultCount - 1;

   } catch(Exception e) {

       result = new BasicDBList();
       result.add(new BasicDBObject("error", "We were not able to retrieve all products with pageSize: " + pageSize + " and pageNumber " + pageNum + ". " + e.getLocalizedMessage() ));

   }

   return Response.ok( result ).header("Content-Range",  "items " + firstItem + "-" + lastItem + "/" + allProductsCount).build();
   ```

   }

   @GET
   @Produces("application/json")
   @Path("/product/grid/?{sort}")
   @HeaderParam("range")
   public Response listProductsWithSort(@HeaderParam("range") String range, @PathParam("sort") String sorting) {

   ```
   Response response = null;

   return response;
   ```

   }

   @PUT
   @Produces("application/json")
   @Path("/product")
   public String createProduct(String productJson) {
       DBObject product = null;
       String result;
       try{
           product = (DBObject)JSON.parse(productJson);
           WriteResult wResult =this.products.insert(product);
           result = wResult.toString();
       }
       catch(Exception e){
           result = "{ error: 'We were not able to insert the product.' " + e.getLocalizedMessage() + " }";
       }

   ```
   return result;
   ```

   }

   @POST
   @Produces("application/json")
   @Path("/product/{productId}")
   public String updateProduct(@PathParam("productId") Integer productId, String productJson) {
       DBObject product = null;
       DBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
       String result = null;
       try{
           product = (DBObject)JSON.parse(productJson);
           query.put("productId", productId.toString());
           WriteResult wResult = this.products.update(query, product);
           result = wResult.toString();
       }
       catch(Exception e){
           result = "{ error: 'We were not able to update the product.' " + e.getLocalizedMessage() + " }";
       }

   ```
   return result;
   ```

   }

   @DELETE
   @Produces("application/json")
   @Path("/product/{productId}")
   public String deleteProduct(@PathParam("productId") Integer productId) {

   ```
   return "{ error: 'This function is not implemented [delete].' }";
   ```

   }

   private DBObject itemToGridConverter(DBObject product) {
       DBObject item = new BasicDBObject();
       BasicDBList images = (BasicDBList)product.get("images");
       BasicDBObject firstImage = (BasicDBObject)images.get(0);

   ```
   item.put("productId", product.get("productId"));
   item.put("sku", product.get("sku"));
   item.put("image", firstImage.get("imageurl"));

   BasicDBList spec = (BasicDBList)product.get("productSpecifics");
   BasicDBObject firstSpec = (BasicDBObject)spec.get(0);

   BasicDBObject attributes = (BasicDBObject)product.get("productAttributes");
   item.put("name", firstSpec.get("title"));
   item.put("cost", "no source");
   item.put("list_price", attributes.get("defaultsalePrice"));
   item.put("qty_available", product.get("qtyonHand"));
   item.put("condition", "no source");
   item.put("active", "true".equals(product.get("active")) ? "Yes" : "No");
   item.put("manufacturer", attributes.get("manufacturer"));
   item.put("part_number", attributes.get("manufacturerPartNumber"));
   item.put("date_created", product.get("_id"));
   return item;
   ```

   }

   }

Thanks much.

**UPDATE:**

I fixed the issue by fixing the path. The issue was how MULE resolves scope boundaries and here the original @Path / was actually in the previous scope. Now that we changed the flow the @Path became /controllers/.
Uyodiin Mevin.

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace of the exception that you are getting?

Comment: No exception, no error. Just a 404. Like this https://localhost:8090/controllers/product/grid/ will give you a 404.

Comment: Satish, your comment made me rethink and I fixed it. The issue is NOT with Jersey, it doesn't care about the https side of the story, the container is dealing with it just fine. I will edit a little what i posted.

Comment: Could you post your update as an answer and accept it? That would bring closure to this question.